# delete values of cells in the last column created

Tags: excel, vba

I have been working on a code that copy the last column and insert a new one, copying its formula and format. However, I need to delete the values of the cells from row `6` to `24` and then from `56` to `78` in the new column created. I couldn't find a way to refer to those cells in order to delete their values, could anyone help me on this? My code is below:

```
Sub Copy_Column()
   Dim LastCol As Integer
   With Worksheets("BO_Corretora")
       LastCol = .Cells(4, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
       Columns(LastCol).Copy
       Columns(LastCol + 1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats
       Columns(LastCol + 1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormulas
   End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `intersect`.  This keeps the rows to be deleted easy to read and you could store them in a constant for easy editing if required.

```
Sub Copy_Column()
    Dim LastCol As Integer
    Dim NewCol As String

    With Worksheets("BO_Corretora")
        LastCol = .Cells(4, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
        .Columns(LastCol).Copy
        .Columns(LastCol + 1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats
        .Columns(LastCol + 1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormulas

        Intersect(.Columns(LastCol + 1), .Range("6:24,56:78")).ClearContents
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are trying?

```
Sub Copy_Column()
    Dim LastCol As Integer
    Dim NewCol As String

    With Worksheets("BO_Corretora")
        LastCol = .Cells(4, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
        .Columns(LastCol).Copy
        .Columns(LastCol + 1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats
        .Columns(LastCol + 1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormulas

        '~~> Get the Column Letter of the new column
        NewCol = Split(.Cells(, LastCol + 1).Address, "$")(1)

        '~~> Range would be like Range("A6:A24,A56:A78")
        .Range(NewCol & "6:" & NewCol & "24," & _
               NewCol & "56:" & NewCol & "78").ClearContents
    End With
End Sub
```